# Attach custom email header for Amazon SES service

Tags: php, email-headers, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon SES to send emails, I would like to attach a custom header to it before it gets sent to users since I'm making a proxy email system, for replying to threads on my site, so the ID is kept for tracking which thread to post to with the email.

I cannot see how I can attach a custom header from Amazon SES' documentation, apart from [this page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Headers.html) which explains on what headers they accept but doesn't say how to bind it, I am using this [SES wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-aws-ses/) made for PHP.

I want to be able to inject a header named `X-Thread-ID` with a number, how would I go on with this?

---

EDIT: For Jack's answer, I cannot send an email properly, it keeps giving me this error:

```
CFSimpleXML Object
(
    [Type] => Sender
    [Code] => InvalidParameterValue
    [Message] => Missing final '@domain'
)
```

My headers is exactly like this

```
To: myemail@hotmail.co.uk <YES>
From: developer@mysite.com <MySite>
X-Thread-ID: 429038
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how attached you are to your current wrapper, but I just use the one that comes with Amazon SDK for PHP that can be downloaded from Amazon itself.

```
$ses = new AmazonSES(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET);

$headers = join("\r\n", array(
    "To: $recipient",
    "X-Thread-ID: 123test",
));
$body = "<html><body> ... </body></html>";

$res = $ses->send_raw_email(array(
    'Data' => chunk_split(base64_encode("$headers\r\n\r\n$body"))
), array());

// check API result
if (!$res->isOK()) {
    throw new Exception(print_r($res->body->Error, true));
}
// inspect message id
$messageId = (string)$res->body->SendRawEmailResult->MessageId
```

**Edit**

This email header:

```
To: myemail@hotmail.co.uk <YES>
```

Should be (reversed):

```
To: YES <myemail@hotmail.co.uk>
```

Double quotes should be used for names with spaces.

Comment: +1 for the official SDK. Quick, easy, and straight from Amazon.

Comment: @Jack I have a question regarding an error I am experiencing.

Comment: OH! Sorry, I forgot to say that I have edited my post - you can read it from there, sorry!

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter That's an easy mistake, updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Fast-forward to 2017, the answer now is (according to Amazon):

(ref: [Send an Email by Accessing the Amazon SES SMTP Interface Programmatically](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-programmatically.html))

```
<?php

// Modify the path in the require statement below to refer to the 
// location of your Composer autoload.php file.
require 'path_to_sdk_inclusion';

// Instantiate a new PHPMailer 
$mail = new PHPMailer;

// Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address. 
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
$mail->setFrom('sender@example.com', 'Sender Name');

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
// Also note that you can include several addAddress() lines to send
// email to multiple recipients.
$mail->addAddress('recipient@example.com', 'Recipient Name');

// Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
$mail->Username = 'smtp_username';

// Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
$mail->Password = 'smtp_password';

// Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
// set, comment or remove the next line.
$mail->addCustomHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', 'ConfigSet');

// If you're using Amazon SES in a region other than US West (Oregon), 
// replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP  
// endpoint in the appropriate region.
$mail->Host = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';

// The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint.
$mail->Port = 465;

// The subject line of the email
$mail->Subject = 'Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using PHP)';

// The HTML-formatted body of the email
$mail->Body = '<h1>Email Test</h1>
    <p>This email was sent through the 
    <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/ses">Amazon SES</a> SMTP
    interface using the <a href="https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer">
    PHPMailer</a> class.</p>';

// Tells PHPMailer to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

// Enable SSL encryption
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

// Tells PHPMailer to send HTML-formatted email
$mail->isHTML(true);

// The alternative email body; this is only displayed when a recipient
// opens the email in a non-HTML email client. The \r\n represents a 
// line break.
$mail->AltBody = "Email Test\r\nThis email was sent through the 
    Amazon SES SMTP interface using the PHPMailer class.";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Email not sent. " , $mail->ErrorInfo , PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "Email sent!" , PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```